# How to convert "slugified-title" to "Slugified Title"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slug

I'm using [angular-slugify](https://github.com/paulsmith/angular-slugify) to make a slug out of a title input. But is there any way to restore it back to title? Im new to angularjs and there is seem no resource for title restoration.

> UPDATE

How can to convert `this-is-a-slug-title` to `This Is A Slug Title` in `angularjs` or `javascript`? It may be advanced for me as a beginner but your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you have access to the title? Read the property that slugify reads from?

Comment: i could do that in the same view and controller but i passed the slugified title to the routeParams and this will be access in the next controller so i dont want to pass two variables to the next controller and instead of that i would simply convert it back to title again and display it in the template.

Comment: "Slugification" is a lossy operation. That basically means it's not guaranteed you can recover the original string. If you still want to do that though, how would you do that manually, on paper? Explain the detailed steps.

Comment: @zerkms hi there, i dont have any logic to make a detailed step for inverse slugification but someone told me you can create it.

Comment: So, if you were given "this-is-a-slug-title" string you would not be able to write it back de-slugified? "but someone told me you can write it" --- I surely could!

Comment: yes because it may be so advanced for me to create it as a beginner here that is why i came to post some question and get helped if someone could lend.

Comment: Well, you will not learn anything from a complete solution. Again, if you were given a "this-is-a-slug-title", would you be able to write down, on paper, with your hand, a de-slugified result? Forget about JS for a second.

Comment: yes of course..

Comment: So, explain how you would do that, step by step (as detailed as possible)

Comment: i think im gonna comeback here later to try it :) wait a moment

Comment: @zerkms hi there thanks for your help i was able to do my stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a simple custom function to convert the slugified string back to normal by splitting the string to array and make each item to have a first char uppercase and joins the array back as string.

```
function inverse_slugify(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase()
            .split('-')
            .map(i => i[0].toUpperCase() + i.substr(1))
            .join(' ');
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/KWyvzY)